# retrieve data from mysql and display it in a table using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve all data from my database and displaying it in a table. But i could not do that, am facing some problem.I am getting error as,

> This page isn’t working.
>
> localhost is currently unable to handle this request.

Here is my code,

```
<html>
<body>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Driverid</th>
    <th>Truckid</th> 
    <th>Imagecount</th>
    <th>Trainingstatus</th>
  </tr>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "IDdb";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT DriverID, TruckID, Imagecount, Trainingstatus FROM IDs";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $driverid = $row["Driverid"];
    $truckid = $row["Truckid"];
    $imagecount = $row["Imagecount"];
    $trainingstatus = $row["Trainingstatus"];?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $driverid; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $truckid; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $imagecount; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $trainingstatus; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
    <?php}
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: localhost is currently unable to handle this request. this error is not releted to your program

Comment: other pages working fine?

Comment: yes other pages are working fine.its not network issue

Comment: check my answer i think it should work

Answer (score 0):

please replace your code

from

```
driverid = $row["Driverid"];
truckid = $row["Truckid"];
imagecount = $row["Imagecount"];
trainingstatus = $row["Trainingstatus"];
```

to

```
$driverid = $row["Driverid"];
$truckid = $row["Truckid"];
$imagecount = $row["Imagecount"];
$trainingstatus = $row["Trainingstatus"];
```

Comment: I am sorry thats a mistake from my side.i have given it wrong.I have changed driverid to $driverid though its not working

Answer (score 0):

please reader the section about how to define variables in php on the  [PHP Manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) ,after that, check the variables defined in your code.

Comment: I have mentioned it wrongly,variable is not a problem.I have changed from driverid to $driverid though its not working

Comment: the braces  in `<?php}`  should be a newline.

Answer (score 0):

you have not started table tag, also  not in loop, and main part is sdd space `<?php}` to `<?php }`

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
echo '<table>';
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $driverid = $row["Driverid"];
    $truckid = $row["Truckid"];
    $imagecount = $row["Imagecount"];
    $trainingstatus = $row["Trainingstatus"];?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $driverid; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $truckid; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $imagecount; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $trainingstatus; ?></td>
  </tr>
    <?php }
echo '</table>';
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: no its not working.I think problem is with the loop,if i print  one data it it working fine.

Comment: have you checked with this code ? because i have tested it

Comment: just debug loop I think you have problem with <?php tag .